# How can I pass values to modal (for multiple records)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a page where I can edit some students info on database,
This is my HTML:

```
 echo '<table width="700" border="1" id="datesNamesT" class="datesNamesT">';
    echo '<tbody>';
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="256" align="left" id="datesNamesTTD" class="datesNamesTTD" style="border-style: none;">' . 'Dr. ' . $ro[STUFName"] . '  ' . $ro["STULName"] . ' ' . $ro["STU_id"] .'</td>';

        echo '<td width="140" align="center" style="border-style: none;">
        <div class="containerr">
                          <div class="interior">


                            <a class="btn" href="#open-modal">Open Modal</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
                          <div>
                            <a href="" title="Close" class="modal-close">Close</a>
                            <h1>Select Date and Time</h1>';
                            echo '<div>' . $ro[STUFName"] . '  ' . $ro["STULName"] . '</div>'; 
                            echo '<br>
                                <div class="container">
                                      <div class="round">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Saturday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Saturday">Saturday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Sunday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Sunday">Sunday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Monday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Monday">Monday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Tuesday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Tuesday">Tuesday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Wednesday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Wednesday">Wednesday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Thursday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Thursday">Thursday</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="Friday" class="cb"/>
                                        <label for="Friday">Friday</label>
                                      </div>
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
```

My main code is working fine but, my problem is whenever i press "Open Modal" the modal will give me values for first student only on database (It works only for first row) it gives me the data for first row for every "Open Modal" I click.
**This is a pic from what I am working on**
[image]

so basically I want the modal to work for every student not just the first one. Thank you

Comment: If the modal is loaded with ajax, then you can pass the StudentID via a GET variable to the URL which loads the modal, and then use that variable to find the right student. Please be aware of SQL Injection though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use AJAX example:

Feed the id to your button for each student example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit_student" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Then create a ajax code to retrieve the data of the student to render in the modal:

```
$('.edit_student').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url:"/getStudentDetails.php",
    data:{id:id},
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(res){
          //feed the data to the modal here
          $('#student_name').val(res.student_name);//example
          $('#open-modal').modal('show');

    }
  });

});
```